# Problem merging/clipping MODIS rasters in QGIS

Tags: qgis, merge, modis, ndvi

Im pretty new to QGIS and am having some trouble making a NDVI map for Mali. To cover the whole country I need 5 MODIS NDVI tiles, however every time I try to merge them I get a "the following layers were not correctly generated" error message. I get the same message when I try to clip the rasters with my underlying polygon (state borders). I have tried to read through past threads but nothing seems to work and I am getting a bit desperate. [image]

Comment: You should avoid to use spaces in some directories  in  your paths to files raster.